# Pass mapkit data between two view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, mapkit

I have two view controllers. One of them is a search view controller which uses mapkit to allow the user to search for a location. [image]

I want to be able to click on a specific cell, and then assign the subtitle of the cell to a textfield in another viewcontroller. Does anyone have ANY idea on how to do this?! 
[image]

Comment: try to think about delegate

Comment: Do you want to instantly go to next view controller when you click on the cell?

Comment: Yes, I would like it to instantly go to the next view controller when clicking the cell. That would be perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You can implement below method of `UITableViewDelegate`.

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)

        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! MyCell
        let vc = MyViewController()
        vc.subtitle = cell.subTitle.text
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

```
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "tosecondVC", sender: indexpath.row)

            }
        }
        override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

            let index = segue.destination as! secondViewController
            index.indexinSecondVC = sender as! Int

        }
```

Comment: what is "index.indexinSecondVC" ?

Comment: indexinSecondVC is your variable in the second VC where you are passing the data, you are passing the data to this variable. You have to create this variable in second VC before passing the data